# I can't get setSpan working

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have an string for e.g: "@user liked your photo! 2h ago" in thin typeface.

This string consists of 3 parts;

1: @user -> it should be typeface.normal and clickable

2: liked your photo! -> this stays the same (thin and black colored)

3: 2h ago -> this should be colored gray.

```
Spannable spannedTime = new SpannableString(time);
Spannable clickableUsername = new SpannableString(username);
clickableUsername.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0, clickableUsername.length(), 0); // this is for 1st part to make it normal typeface
spannedTime.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, spannedTime.length(), 0); // this is for 3rd part to make it gray

clickableUsername.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CallProfileActivity();
    }
}, 0, clickableUsername.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);// this is for 1st part to make it clickable

this.setText(clickableUsername + " " + notificationBody + " " + spannedTime);
```

But none of them has any effects.

Comment: Define "not working"... What does `CallProfileActivity();` do?

Comment: see BackgroundColorSpan, StyleSpan and ClickableSpan none of them are working. CallProfileActivity(); works quite right it just opens an activity.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] so we could try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The java compiler doesn't know about `Spannable`. When you do

```
this.setText(clickableUsername + " " + notificationBody + " " + spannedTime);
```

java creates a `String` concatination all the `SpannableString`.

To create a spannable string like you intent to do, you should use [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html).

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder();
spannable.append(clickableUsername, new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0);
spannable.append(' ').append(notificationBody).append(' ');
spannable.append(time, new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0);
spannable.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CallProfileActivity();
    }
}, 0, username.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
this.setText(spannable);
```